# Efficient method to find Cofactor of Laplacian Matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, determinant, graph-laplacian

I want to find number of Spanning tree of "Simple connected graph". After some research i found it is equal to co-factor of any element of its "Laplacian Matrix".
I remove first row and first column of Laplacian matrix, and then convert it into upper triangular matrix to find its Determinant. But this approach takes $O(n^3)$ time for graph with $n$ nodes.
Since it is Laplacian Matrix i think there must exist some better approach with less complexity. 
What if Laplacian matrix is sparse or only few elements are $0$ in it. Can these cases will solve much more efficiently.
Please Suggest some link, theorem or solution to efficiently solve this problem.

Comment: For any $n\times n$-matrix $A$, you can find a directed edge-weighted graph with $n+1$ vertices such that $A$ is a submatrix of its Laplacian. So you shouldn't gain much from knowing that a matrix is such a submatrix.

Comment: May you elaborate??

Comment: If you had a fast algorithm that worked for cofactors of Laplacian matrices, then you could apply it to any matrix, because it is easy to extend any matrix to a (edge-weighted) Laplacian by adding an extra row and an extra column.

Comment: Ok, so what if graph has only few edges short to become complete graph?? can this problem has an efficient approach.

Comment: In cases like that, yeah, there's likely to be a better way.

Comment: May you suggest an efficient algorithm for finding determinant of sparse matrix or any link/tutorial about it. I think thins problem can easily reduce to sparse matrix.